# inverse match regex AND Space or end of string, AND space or start of string

Tags: java, regex

I need to match a regex on Java when a string does NOT contains an email anywhere in the string: the beginning, middle or end. 
 For example:

```
string with no email [match]

myMail@mail.com string with email at the start [no match]

String with myMail@mail.com in the middle [no match]

String with email at the end myMail@mail.com [no match]

myMail@mail.com [no match]
```

The regex I have managed to come up with so far is an inverse version of a popular email regex:

```
"^(?![_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$).*$)";
```

works for me only when I have just an email;

```
myMail@mail.com [no match]
```

but I need it to give me no match for ALL the examples containing an email.
Any ideas how it can be done? Thanks

edited:

Found the answer by looking at

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

The working line is:

```
"^((?![_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})).)*$)";
```

Thanks

Comment: How about `!line.matches("\\w+@\\w+\\.\\w+")`, or something similar?

Comment: You should add `.*` before the email pattern in the lookahead, and perhaps, add a DOTALL modifier to ensure you check for the email on any line: `"(?s)^(?!.*[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+(?:\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(?:\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$).*$"`